# Is it possible to instantiate a custom class in FXML code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, javafx, fxml

I've extended the javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas class to be resizable.
Is it possible to write something similar to this in FXML?

```
<ResizableCanvas fx:id="..." ></ResizableCanvas >
```

If i do this I get an exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: ResizableCanvas is not a valid type.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)
```

That means I can only use my class only in java code?

In WPF it's possible to use the customized class in XAML code. I am looking for something similar..

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible to use a "custom" class in FXML code. All that's required is that the class is on the classpath at runtime, and can be resolved by the FXML parser. The latter means that either you need the fully-qualified class name, or you need an import for your class in the FXML preamble.

Note that FXML does not play nicely with the default package, so classes in the default package may not load. Default packages are highly non-recommended anyway.

So typically you would have something like:

```
package com.example ;

public class ResizableCanvas {

    // ...
}
```

which you can use with

```xml
<?import com.example.ResizableCanvas ?>
<!-- other imports ... -->

<-- ... -->
<ResizableCanvas fx:id="..." />
```